# Unable to locate package mysql-server

Tags: apt, software-installation, mysql

I installed ubuntu 16.04, after that when i try to install mysql it shows error as

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for mcerc: 
Reading package lists... Done
mcerc@mcerc-ThinkCentre-M72e:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
mcerc@mcerc-ThinkCentre-M72e:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
mcerc@mcerc-ThinkCentre-M72e:~$ ^C
mcerc@mcerc-ThinkCentre-M72e:~$
```

Answer (score 17):

Whenever u install fresh Ubuntu , you need to update and upgrade the system to install from ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now install anything

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: You're geneous +1

Comment: @ViperTecPro haha. :)

Comment: Nope, this is the WRONG answer. OP (original poster) has already posted the output of `sudo apt update`. It went without any errors... This is the wrong answer. The correct answer is "All your repositories are disabled, open software properties gtk and enable all the repositories and run `apt update` and install MySQL again."

Answer (score 4):

- First, goto `Ubuntu Software` and in the menu there will be the option `Ubuntu Software`. Select it.
- There, you will `Softwares and Updates`. Select it. Check if all the official repositories (under the option `Ubuntu Software`)  are checked. If not then check them.
- Else use the following command for installing mysql-server `sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7`. This should work.

UPDATE: `Ubuntu Software` tab is moved to `Software & Update`, a separate application in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can't very well go to Ubuntu Software via the command line...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem : mysql-server maybe was installed once and the settings in your machine might be saved somewhere . Remove it completely with .

Uninstall mysql-server first:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server
```

install it again. Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This also help to fix broken packages, so if these commands above failed tried to fix packages first and then remove and install the mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: how to remove mysql completely https://help.cloud66.com/maestro/how-to-guides/databases/shells/uninstall-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. I had an issue installing `openssh-server` on my Ubuntu 16. I tried above solution and it installs `openssh-server` successfully.
Here is what I tries:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server 
sudo apt-get install openssh-server 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: it is not related ``openssh-server ``  its related ``mysql-server`` kindly post the relevant answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

The other answers should work normally, but for me something was circularly misconfigured somehow and `sudo apt purge mysql* -y`
just gave me

> E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb

but also
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
just gave me

> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
> installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> mysql-server-8.0
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So I thought if apt can't handle it on it's own, I'll bring on the big guy: `dpkg`

First I queried all packages containing mysql with

```
sudo dpkg-query -l | less | grep mysql
```

then I purged all of them one by one like

```
sudo dpkg --purge mysql-common
sudo dpkg --purge mysql-server-8.0
sudo dpkg --purge mysql-server-core-8.0
...
```

Then I ran all the commands suggested here + `sudo apt autoremove`, so after that I could reinstall it just like normal.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and here is how I resolved it:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).